# Adding an http header site wide in php

Tags: php, http-headers

I'm maintaining a web site for a non-profit organisation. I'm not the one who designed this web site, and I don't know the person who did it.

That said, I have an issue with IE9. I will eventually try to correct it, but meanhile just adding the `X-UA-Compatible` header so IE9 turns to IE8 mode would work just fine.

In an asp.net web site, I would add it in the web.config with the `<customHeaders>` element (with IIS7).

Is there's a way to send this header for all file in a php web site, without editing all files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache MOD_HEADERS, add the following to your root .htaccess file

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php|cgi|pl|htm)$">
    Header set X-UA-Compatible IE=EmulateIE8
</FilesMatch>
```

This will set that header in the http header of all php, html, perl and cgi files, but I have had very bad experiences with the x-ua header, and found that it doesn't always work.

Comment: About the x-ua header, I know that it may not be taken into account when in localhost or local network.

The string in FilesMatch is a regular expression? Meaning "anything that ends with one of thes extension"?

Answer (score 1):

[`auto_prepend_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) and `header()`, or configure it in your web server with e.g. [`Header`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#header).

Comment: `auto_prepend_file` in php.ini seems to be what I need. Can I just drop a php.ini file in my root folder so it will be merged with the server's one?

Comment: Keep in mind that this may send this header with all your PHP pages, even ones not in this particular website (depending on your server config).

Comment: @Johnny5: Generally no. How it can be done depends on the SAPI being used.

Comment: @Johhny5: better to throw it in a `.htaccess`, assuming you're using Apache.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using some kind of templating engine, you could just add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" /> to the HEAD section of your template(s).

Otherwise, if you're including a single PHP file everywhere, you could add a header() call there (as long as it's before you output any content).