# Adding html headers to frames with Apache mod_headers (other modules?)

Tags: html, apache, perl, http-headers

I am trying to make existing IE5 web-portal compatible with IE11.
It is written in "Enhanced Perl-parsed HTML" (*.ephtml) and seem to work in IE11 well with "Compatibility View Settings" turned on.
Unfortunately solution should work without any configuration on user side.

I found that Compatibility View can be turned on by adding tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5" />
```

without any changes on client side.

And that Apache can be configured to add this tag to every page using

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
Header set X-UA-Compatible “IE=IE5”
```

in httpd.con
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cc817573.aspx)
([Adding an http header site wide in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933509/adding-an-http-header-site-wide-in-php/6933596#6933596))

This doesn't solve problem entirely, since many of the portal pages are mage up from frames and this header isn't being inserted into frame pages.
Therefore many pages with frames are broken (but work correctly if Compatibility View is turned on Browser Wide)

Is there any way to add this header automatically to all frames using Apache configurations?
Only other solution I can see right now is modifying all the pages, manually inserting this header.

Comment: Personally, I never liked frames. I would suggest not using them. That aside, you could use an html parser to add the desired meta tag to the frame tags in all pages automatically instead of manually. Might be costly on performance, so perhaps a regex would also do.